# How to use pywinrm to execute powershell commands?

Tags: python, powershell

I am using Linux machine with Python 2.6 and want to execute few PowerShell commands on remote windows server.

I have used pywinrm and below is the code:

```
import winrm
st = winrm.Session('ABC0634176', auth=('Administrator', '#root123'))
r = st.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
```

But getting below error:

[image]

Please help to get the solution, how can I run the PowerShell command.
Is there any other library for the same purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kerberos: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056706/kerberos-bad-http-response-returned-from-server-code-500)

Comment: I think 502 is obvious: Bad Gateway