# Bad HTTP response returned from the server. Code 500

Tags: python, powershell, active-directory, kerberos, winrm

I have a problem to use pywinrm on linux, to get a PowerShell Session. 
I read several posts and questions on sites about that. But  any that can solve my question.

The error is in the Kerberos autentication. This is my krb5.conf:

```
 0  [libdefaults] 
 1         default_realm = DOMAIN.COM.BR                                                                                                                          
 2         ticket_lifetime = 24000                                                                                                                                       
 3         clock-skew = 300                                                                                                                                              
 4         dns_lookup_kdc = true                                                                                                                                         
 5                                                                                                                                                                       
 6 # [realms]                                                                                                                                                            
 7 #         LABCORP.CAIXA.GOV.BR = {                                                                                                                                    
 8 #                 kdc = DOMAIN.COM.BR                                                                                                              
 9 #                 kdc = DOMAIN.COM.BR                                                                                                              
10 #                 admin_server = DOMAIN.COM.BR                                                                                         
11 #                 default_domain = DOMAIN.COM.BR                                                                                                        
12 #         }                                                                                                                                                           
13
14 [logging]                                                                                                                                                             
15                                                                                                                                                                       
16     default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log                                                                                                                                  
17     kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log                                                                                                                                       
18     admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log                                                                                                                              
19                                                                                                                                                                       
20 # [domain_realm]                                                                                                                                                      
21 #         .DOMAIN.COM.BR  = DOMAIN.COM.BR 
22 #         server.com = DOMAIN.COM.BR
```

My /etc/resolv.conf is:

```
search DOMAIN.COM.BR 
nameserver IP
```

And my python code is:

```
import winrm

s = winrm.Session(
    'DOMAIN.COM.BR ',
    'transport='kerberos',
    auth=('my_active_directory_user', 'my_active_directory_password'),
    server_cert_validation='ignore')

r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
```

And the server return this error:

```
winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: ('http', 'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500')
```

The port of the server is open. I see with nmap:

```
5985/tcp  open  wsman
```

I can ping and resolv the name of the server:

```
$ ping DOMAIN.COM.BR 

PING DOMAIN.COM.BR  (IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from IP: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.410 ms
64 bytes from IP: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.410 ms
```

I can use kinit without problem to get the ticket:

```
$ kinit my_active_directory_user@DOMAIN.COM.BR
```

And, list the ticket:

```
$ klist

Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: my_active_directory_user@DOMAIN.COM.BR 

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05-09-2017 10:23:52  05-09-2017 17:03:50  krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM.BR @DOMAIN.COM.BR
```

What kind of problem is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution is to add this line with `allow_weak_crypto` in your `krb5.conf` file:

```
[libdefaults]
     ***
     allow_weak_crypto = true
     ***
```